# Convert datetime to MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS AM/PM

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to convert the below date into the output as shown. I can get the date part using the code 101 but for the time I could not find any code that translates the time to HH:MM:SS AM/PM? Any ideas please? Thank you!

```
declare @adddate datetime

Set @adddate = 2011-07-06T22:30:07.5205649-04:00

Convert(varchar, @adddate, 101) + ' ' + 
    Convert(varchar, @adddate, 108)
```

The output should be:

```
07/06/2011 10:30:07 PM
```

Comment: are you using some sort of reporting software? is this being used by an application?  sounds like you are trying to format data for viewing purposes?

Comment: Your SET doesn't even work. Also, [never use `varchar` without length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Comment: Also your desired output shows d/m/y but your title shows m/d/y. Can you please confirm (and explain why you want to make your output confusing)? `@adddate` represents July 6th, right? See why using m/d/y or d/m/y can be confusing?

Comment: I am sorry about that part. I meant to say the output s/b 07/06/2011. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current `SET` doesn't even work. When you have a *valid* datetime value coming in from a string literal, you can do this:

```
DECLARE @adddate DATETIME;

SET @adddate = '2011-07-06T22:30:07.521';

SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(11), @adddate, 103) 
  + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), @adddate, 22), 11));
```

Result:

```
06/07/2011 10:30:07 PM
```

If you actually want m/d/y (your question is ambiguous), there is a slightly shorter path using style 22:

```
DECLARE @adddate DATETIME;

SET @adddate = '2011-07-06T22:30:07.521';

SELECT STUFF(CONVERT(CHAR(20), @adddate, 22), 7, 2, YEAR(@adddate));
```

Result:

```
07/06/2011 10:30:07 PM
```

However, this is a bad idea for two reasons:

1. regional formats are confusing (will a reader know 05/06/2013 is May 6th and not June 5th? Depends on where they're from) and even dangerous (if they pass that string back in, you might store June 5th when they meant May 6th).
2. your client language is better off using it's own `Format()` or `ToString()` methods to format this for display at the very last moment possible.

Answer (score 1):

There's no format option in `convert` for that. You'll need to use [DATEPART()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) instead and build up the new string from the individual components:

```
DATEPART(@adddate, hh) + ':' + DATEPART(@adddate, mi) + etc...
```

Comment: You've got your datepart arguments backwards. Also why not just spell out `HOUR` and `MINUTE`? The shorthand can be ambiguous and even confusing (check out what `y` and `w` do, for example - not what most people expect).