# Date Format in SQL dd/mm/yyyy hr:mm:ss AM/PM

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date-formatting

What is the format to be used in SQL to get date in format like

```
dd/mm/yyyy hr:mm:ss AM/PM
```

eg: `9/17/2013  4:55:43 PM`

The link below gives an answer but i want value in seconds also

[How to display Date in DD/MM/YYYY H:MM AM/PM format in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420795/how-to-display-date-in-dd-mm-yyyy-hmm-am-pm-format-in-sql-server)

Instead of 101 in below query.

```
convert(varchar, CONVERT(smalldatetime, PhaseStartDate), 101)
```

Comment: `dd/mm/yyyy` and `9/17/2013`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date format returned as mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26063902/date-format-returned-as-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmmss-am-pm)

Comment: Please don't use `convert(varchar, .....)` - you should **always** explicitly define the **length** for your `varchar` type - like this: `convert(varchar(20), .....)` . Otherwise, you'll get some defaults - do you know what defaults are in place here, and whether those are OK for you??

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using. If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later you can use the `FORMAT()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh213505.aspx) function. I would **strongly** advise though, that you leave formatting to the presentation layer.

Comment: You need to clarify: `dd/mm` or `mm/dd`?

Answer (score 1):

You can check both posts below...
They convert to mm/dd instead of dd/mm

but to get what you want, just change to 103 instead of 101 ;)

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26063902/date-format-returned-as-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmmss-am-pm)
[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020825/convert-datetime-to-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmmss-am-pm)

Answer (score 1):

```
   select convert(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 103 /*or 101*/) + ' ' +
   ltrim(right(convert(varchar(20), GETDATE(), 22), 11))
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you meant 103 or mm/dd/yyyy instead. You could craft that yourself from the pieces or combine and craft from two or more styles.

IMHO, that should be something you do in your front end.

Answer (score 0):

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), PhaseStartDate, 101) + Substring((CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), PhaseStartDate, 22)),9,12) as PhaseStartDate
```

Useful Link is here
http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're not using SQL Server 2005.
here is your query

```
SELECT 
     CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),103) +' '+ 
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CAST( GETDATE() AS TIME ))+' '+
     SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 9), 25, 2)
```