# Insert complete Date format Records with AM and PM in OLEDB Destination by using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis

I have One FlatFile Source and One OLEDB Destination.
Flatfile Source contains date format like **dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS: AM** but when I am trying to load the data into the OLEDB Destination the inserted record format is like **"yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS"** it was not loaded the AM or PM.

> > But I need Output like **yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS AM**

Example--->

> > I/P:**10/07/2015 06:05:22 AM**
> >     
> > Needed O/P: **10/07/2015 06:05:22 AM**

Comment: What data type is the target field? If it is `datetime`, then the output format shown can be altered with use of a `CONVERT` function. datetime (and date etc.) fields have no format. Its just what you happen to see when you select data out of it in your particular tool. If you use a different tool it might come out in a different format. Date formatting is a 'client side' operation. What tool are you viewing this in and why do you care about the format?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Nick.

Comment: My Target Datatype is Datetime and destination is SQL Server 2012.

How can we achive this. Please help me out on this.

Thanks,
Bharadwaj

Comment: The input is irrelevant here. The data is stored as a date which _has no format_. You're only interested in the output. I answered an identical question yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412863/date-format-in-sql-dd-mm-yyyy-hrmmss-am-pm/33413048#33413048